# Monotouch uialertview size problem

Tags: ios, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, uialertview

I want to use uialertview on my iPad app.
Also i use monotouch but i cannot change alertview size. 
How can i change size alertview? 
Do u have any idea?
 I want put some object on alertview. (uilabel,uitextfield)

Comment: I am having the same problem. I am not using buttons on the alertview so I want that extra space.

Answer (score 3):

There are several examples of customizing UIAlertView [here](http://www.shrinkrays.net/code-snippets/csharp/monotouch-tips-and-snippets.aspx) and [here](http://www.kevfoo.com/2009/11/monotouch-uialertview-uitextfield-crazy-delicious).

Comment: And another one here: http://www.wildsau.net/post/2011/01/28/iOS-UIAlertView-with-a-UITextField-a-MonoTouch-implementation.aspx

Comment: Thank you for answered Jason but It did not usefull for me. However, I have used this examples.